# Number of numbers that when you upside down them continue to be valid numbers

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures

What is the number of numbers between 1 to n ( when n is a very large number) that if you upside down the number you get a valid number that is not equal to itself?

**Valid digits that when you upside down them continue to be valid:**

```
[0,1,6,8,9] => [0,1,9,8,6]
```

**Examples of flipping a number upside down:**

```
989 => 686
981 => 186
```

**Example of an answer to the main question:** if you have **n = 10** the answer is 3. Those three numbers are:

- 6 (because 9 != 6)
- 9 (because 6 != 9)
- 10 (because 10 != 01))

What I've tried is the naive way: Iterating over the numbers `1..n` and checking each number, but this is not efficient when `n` is a large number.

Comment: when you say flip do you mean turning the number upside down?  Is 1 a valid number when it is "flipped"? If so how are the numbers flipped? Does 3 looks like 3 or a backwards 3? Depends on how you flip it.

Comment: as far as I understand only 6 and 9 is a case as any other number "flipped" won't work - only 8 comes to my mind but it's not meeting requirement "is not equal to itself". So actually you need algorithm to search for number with 6 and 9 like 69, 96, 996, etc. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I mean upside down ,For Example: 
696 =>969
189 => 681 
.the numbers that can be stayed valid numbers when you flip them are: 0 1 6 8 9

Comment: For n=10, why does 10 not count? (01!=10)

Comment: I excluded n, but you are right it's count

Comment: How about 2 and 5?

Comment: I think the solution will be: count ALL valid numbers then subtract the ones which are the same after flipping.  ...although I don't know the exact algorithm yet.

Comment: Please update your post with flip values for each digit.

Comment: You can count the K-digit numbers that are flip-valid by: (# of flip-valid single numbers)^K.  Then subtract the K-digit numbers that are flip-equivalent by: (# of flip-equivalent single numbers)^K.  You can do this for each K < (# digit of n). Finally, do case-by-case calculation for finding numbers no greater than n.

Comment: Voted to re-open because the OP clarified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to generate and count all possible numbers that are valid after flipping (will be same number after flipping) recursively.

Here is my C++ implementation:

```
int countValidFlippedNumber(int left, int right, string& str, const int n, bool isLessThanN) {
    if(left > right) {
        if(isLessThanN) {
            return 1;
        }
        int x = atoi(str.c_str());
        if(x <= n)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;

    if((left == 0 and left == right) or left > 0) {
        str[left] = str[right] = '0';
        count += countValidFlippedNumber(left + 1, right - 1, str, n, isLessThanN);
    }

    str[left] = str[right] = '1';
    count += countValidFlippedNumber(left + 1, right - 1, str, n, isLessThanN);
    str[left] = str[right] = '8';
    count += countValidFlippedNumber(left + 1, right - 1, str, n, isLessThanN);

    if(left < right) {
        str[left] = '6'; str[right] = '9';
        count += countValidFlippedNumber(left + 1, right - 1, str, n, isLessThanN);

        swap(str[left], str[right]); // str[left] = '9'; str[right] = '6'; 
        count += countValidFlippedNumber(left + 1, right - 1, str, n, isLessThanN);    
    }
    return count;
}

int validFlippedNumber(int n) {
    int len = to_string(n).length();
    int result = 0;
    string str;
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        str.resize(i);
        result += countValidFlippedNumber(0, i - 1, str, n, true);
    }
    str.resize(len);
    result += countValidFlippedNumber(0, len - 1, str, n, false);
    return result;
}
```